# Tracking nearby mobile phones

Tags: networking

I'm new to the raspberry pi device and I'm thinking about a project that involves **tracking nearby mobile phones for analytics purposes.**

This has nothing to do with listening to conversations or any illegal activity. I just want to KNOW if somebody is nearby by counting **anonymous visits** to a certain place. Furthermore, I'm not willing to violate user's privacy by identifying them personally.

What is the best way to do it?

I thought about tracking them through probe requests that their devices periodically send. But there's probably another better way.

For those questioning that its possible:
1) https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/log-wi-fi-probe-requests-from-smartphones-laptops-with-probemon-0176303/
2) https://www.yetanotherblog.com/2014/03/25/tracking-devices-via-raspberry-pi-part-two/

Thank you in advance

Comment: Regardless of your motives this has nothing to do with the Pi.

Comment: Come on @joan, who wouldn't want an IMSI-catcher for that price?

Comment: Yes, it can: https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/log-wi-fi-probe-requests-from-smartphones-laptops-with-probemon-0176303/

Im just wondering the best way to do it.